# Will it be efficient if I create graph datastructure/algorithms using list in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I begin to write `graph` related `data structure` and `algorithms` in `OCaml` now.

I am willing to try to write them in a functional way in OCaml, i.e., avoiding using `array`, mutable type, etc.

But if I write all those using `list`, will it be efficient or make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use lists for everything. There are many other immutable data structures in the library, or you can define your own. You can think of a graph as a map from nodes to lists of successors. I've written large amounts of graph processing code in OCaml using this representation, and I was always pretty happy with the results.

**Update**

Here's a sketch of the representation I'm talking about. It assumes you label your nodes with uniqe strings. Note that (as monniaux commented) using a list of successors is probably more suitable for sparse graphs than for dense ones.

```
type label = string
module GMap = Map.Make(struct type t = label let compare = compare end)
type 'a node = label * 'a * label list
type 'a graph = 'a node GMap.t

let empty = GMap.empty

let add (label: label) (contents: 'a) successors (graph: 'a graph) : 'a graph =
    GMap.add label (label, contents, successors) graph
```

Make a graph containing just a cycle of length 2:

```
# let g = add "a" () ["b"] (add "b" () ["a"] empty);;
val g : unit graph = <abstr>
```

Comment: Yes. In my work I just used the Map module from the OCaml library.

Comment: ok, so in OCaml/FPL, Map normally adopts BST, in sacrifice of O(1), right?

Comment: My another question is that, if I implement graph using array, mutable records, etc, will that hurt much? as anyway, it will be fastest, right?

Comment: It's usually possible to make the code at least a little faster using imperative constructs. However, it's not *always* faster. The OCaml system (such as GC) is tuned for immutable data. Personally I would recommend (again) that you forget about performance until you've seen some of the advantages of applicative (non-imperative) code. It's virtually always possible to make code go faster by sacrificing some desirable property of the code (such as getting the right answer :-)).

Comment: Note that ocaml has one of the best graph libraries around: http://ocamlgraph.lri.fr/ so unless you're doing this for educational reasons I would suggest to use that extremely useful library.

Comment: BST are not the only way to implement maps, hashtable provide the same core semantics.

Comment: @didierc hashtable in ocaml is using array, which is mutable, right?

Comment: correct! Indeed I forgot to consider that aspect. See the other answer as to how to turn a mutable structure into an immutable one.

Comment: Jeffrey, could you please tell me your type definition for graph if you use Map?

Answer (score 4):

This all depends on the kind of algorithms you wish to implement and whether you wish to consider sparse or dense graphs. A dense graph is usually represented by a matrix (which, by the way, can be kept immutable and used functionally).

If you need arrays with O(1) update (e.g. for marking nodes), you may still use them in a functional way by using a wrapper library that presents arrays as updatable structures, giving a new array each time. The trick is to implement these updates by keeping a mutable array as "head" version and keeping past versions as deltas from "head". This keeps all the imperative issues wrapped up inside a module presenting, semantically at least, a functional interface.

If you have sparse graphs, it is common to talk about "adjacency lists". I think it is a bad idea to use them unless the graph is extremely sparse (nodes with small degree, in absolute terms), because they have O(n) access. Binary trees à la `Set` are, I think, much more suitable, because they allow testing in O(log n).

Comment: These are good points. I had very sparse graphs with a constant limit on the number of adjacent nodes. For dense graphs this structure would probably be too slow.